# Can't check the “Migrate to a physical computer with a different processor version”

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

Due to the problems of "Could not connect to the debugger" in Xamarin.Android,
After I find the solutions from the [Web](http://theothergavin.net/xamarin-app-development-aot-module-mscorlib-dll-so-not-found/#comment-9581) , When I come to the last two step I facing a problems I Can't check [/] the “Migrate to a physical computer with a different processor version”
The Photo as below.

[image: Error in Hyper V]

Comment: The error is implying that your virtual machine is still running. Close any virtualisation software and try again.

Comment: As a side note I would probably recommend _not_ enabling Hyper-V and to use the Google AVD instead. Most people use the Google AVD and it will ensure that you always have the latest API level images available to you.